# Differenet behavior of cmd and powershell in venv

Tags: powershell, cmd, pip, virtualenv, python-venv

I have installed 2 python interpreter 3.7.6 & 3.8.5 in Windows 10.
when i run same command in cmd and powershell i get different answer in virtualenv,why?

```
CMD:

E:\Python_Projects\Django_Projects\PRACTICES\LearnFiles>python --version
Python 3.7.6

E:\Python_Projects\Django_Projects\PRACTICES\LearnFiles>py --version
Python 3.8.5

E:\Python_Projects\Django_Projects\PRACTICES\LearnFiles>pip --version
pip 20.2.4 from c:\users\persi\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)

E:\Python_Projects\Django_Projects\PRACTICES\LearnFiles>py -m pip --version
pip 20.2.4 from C:\Users\persi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)

E:\Python_Projects\Django_Projects\PRACTICES\LearnFiles>pip freeze
appdirs==1.4.4
asgiref==3.3.1
distlib==0.3.1
Django==3.1.3
filelock==3.0.12
importlib-metadata==2.0.0
pytz==2020.4
six==1.15.0
sqlparse==0.4.1
virtualenv==20.2.0
zipp==3.4.0

E:\Python_Projects\Django_Projects\PRACTICES\LearnFiles>py -m pip freeze
bitstring==3.1.7
cycler==0.10.0
json-tricks==3.15.4
kiwisolver==1.3.1
matplotlib==3.3.3
numpy==1.19.4
Pillow==8.0.1
pyparsing==2.4.7
python-dateutil==2.8.1
six==1.15.0

E:\Python_Projects\Django_Projects\PRACTICES\LearnFiles>.\venv\Scripts\activate

(venv) E:\Python_Projects\Django_Projects\PRACTICES\LearnFiles>python --version
Python 3.7.6

(venv) E:\Python_Projects\Django_Projects\PRACTICES\LearnFiles>py --version
Python 3.8.5

(venv) E:\Python_Projects\Django_Projects\PRACTICES\LearnFiles>py -m pip freeze
bitstring==3.1.7
cycler==0.10.0
json-tricks==3.15.4
kiwisolver==1.3.1
matplotlib==3.3.3
numpy==1.19.4
Pillow==8.0.1
pyparsing==2.4.7
python-dateutil==2.8.1
six==1.15.0

(venv) E:\Python_Projects\Django_Projects\PRACTICES\LearnFiles>pip freeze
appdirs==1.4.4
asgiref==3.3.1
distlib==0.3.1
Django==3.1.3
filelock==3.0.12
importlib-metadata==2.0.0
pytz==2020.4
six==1.15.0
sqlparse==0.4.1
virtualenv==20.2.0
zipp==3.4.0
```

PowerShell:

```
E:\Python_Projects\Django_Projects\PRACTICES\LearnFiles> python --version                                         
Python 3.7.6
E:\Python_Projects\Django_Projects\PRACTICES\LearnFiles> py --version                                             
Python 3.8.5
E:\Python_Projects\Django_Projects\PRACTICES\LearnFiles> pip --version                                            
pip 20.2.4 from c:\users\persi\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)
E:\Python_Projects\Django_Projects\PRACTICES\LearnFiles> py -m pip --version                                      
pip 20.2.4 from C:\Users\persi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)
E:\Python_Projects\Django_Projects\PRACTICES\LearnFiles> pip freeze                                               
appdirs==1.4.4
asgiref==3.3.1
distlib==0.3.1
Django==3.1.3
filelock==3.0.12
importlib-metadata==2.0.0
pytz==2020.4
six==1.15.0
sqlparse==0.4.1
virtualenv==20.2.0
zipp==3.4.0
E:\Python_Projects\Django_Projects\PRACTICES\LearnFiles> py -m pip freeze
bitstring==3.1.7
cycler==0.10.0
json-tricks==3.15.4
kiwisolver==1.3.1
matplotlib==3.3.3
numpy==1.19.4
Pillow==8.0.1
pyparsing==2.4.7
python-dateutil==2.8.1
six==1.15.0
E:\Python_Projects\Django_Projects\PRACTICES\LearnFiles> .\venv\Scripts\activate
(venv) PS E:\Python_Projects\Django_Projects\PRACTICES\LearnFiles> python --version
Python 3.7.6
(venv) PS E:\Python_Projects\Django_Projects\PRACTICES\LearnFiles> py --version
Python 3.7.6
(venv) PS E:\Python_Projects\Django_Projects\PRACTICES\LearnFiles> py -m pip freeze
appdirs==1.4.4
asgiref==3.2.10
distlib==0.3.1
Django==3.1.2
django-ckeditor==6.0.0
django-jalali==4.0.0
django-js-asset==1.2.2
filelock==3.0.12
importlib-metadata==1.7.0
jdatetime==3.6.2
pytz==2020.1
six==1.15.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
virtualenv==20.0.31
zipp==3.2.0
(venv) PS E:\Python_Projects\Django_Projects\PRACTICES\LearnFiles> pip freeze
appdirs==1.4.4
asgiref==3.2.10
distlib==0.3.1
Django==3.1.2
django-ckeditor==6.0.0
django-jalali==4.0.0
django-js-asset==1.2.2
filelock==3.0.12
importlib-metadata==1.7.0
jdatetime==3.6.2
pytz==2020.1
six==1.15.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
virtualenv==20.0.31
zipp==3.2.0
```

As you guest above im using django and have problem inside venv.I'm using pycharm and terminal inside it is the same as cmd,and actually i want to see venv in picture below when i use pip freeze in terminal inside pycharm.
[picture of my Aim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qs7KU.png)
Thanks for Answering.

Comment: Are you using the venv `activate.bat` script? Do you have both python.exe and py in the PATH? If so, which one is first?

Comment: if i understood you correctly i used just activate,not activate.bat.yes both are. 3.7 is first.actually my problem will solve after i delete venv and make a new venv and use pip install -r ... . but i wana the reason so that i must not delete and create venv frequently

Comment: Using `activate` is not shown in the question. What about the `PATH` variable?

Comment: E:\Python_Projects\Django_Projects\PRACTICES\LearnFiles>.\venv\Scripts\activate